# Apache config file numbering convention; 000-default etc

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

Is there a widely adopted convention for naming apache configuration files?

I'm working on an Ubuntu machine and the example files is named `000-default`. I recall at a previous project the sysadmin seemed to have an obscure way of choosing the 3-digit prefix to the file names.

I'm curious how most people do this?

Also, does it actually matter all that much? I guess the files are imported in ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files are indeed imported in lexicographical order. How you achieve this ordering is entirely at your discretion, but the easiest method is by prefixing file names with digits/numbers. I'm not aware of any preferred/standardised style for doing this, and what you have described (3 digit prefixes) is a good a method as any. It's fixed length, which also aids visually on a terminal. If you have less than 1000 conf files, 3 digits would make sense. But if you only have up to 100, maybe 2 digits would be better, up to 10 files, single digit, etc etc.

It is also possible to group Apache conf files into sub-directories. Simply create folders like `0.conf`, `1.conf`, and then place conf files in those to achieve ordering on a more grouped basis. Directories must be named `*.conf` to be included. This may be useful if you need to disable an entire group of websites in one go, by simply renaming the directory (`mv name.conf name.off`) and reloading Apache. All conf files under that directory will now have been removed from the configuration.

Note that it does depend on the application as to whether sub-directories are recursively supported. I tried this trick with dnsmasq recently and it doesn't work. Nginx also doesn't support recursively traversing `*.conf` directories (tested against version 1.10.2).